# Why fractional iteration step compiles into different JavaScript than integer step

Tags: coffeescript

I was wondering about slightly different JavaScript which ranges comprehensions in CoffeeScript compiles into. Is there any reason why following differencies in generated JavaScript?

Iterating a range by integer step

```
numbers = (i for i in [start..end] by 2)
```

compiles into:

```
for (i = start; i <= end; i += 2) {
  _results.push(i);
}
```

But when iterating by fractional step

```
numbers = (i for i in [start..end] by 1/2)
```

generates bit more complicated JavaScript:

```
for (i = start, _ref = 1 / 2; start <= end ? i <= end : i >= end; i += _ref) {
  _results.push(i);
}
```

So why this additional `start <= end` condition?

Comment: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get similarly elaborate code if you just do `numbers = (i for i in [start..end])`. This is because CoffeeScript doesn't know which direction the range goes when the beginning or ending is a variable. The compiler has a special optimization where it will output simpler code if a constant step is provided, but unfortunately 1/2 is counted as an expression rather than a constant.

Comment: In case of 'numbers = (i for i in [start..end] by 2)' CoffeeScript doesn't add the additional condition. So as you wrote it seems to be the special optimization. But it would be nice to include also constant expressions...

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript doesn't know completely what the expression 1/2 evaluates to. It could be Math.random() - .5 and it would depend on the particular running of the script.

Therefore, it's impossible for Coffeescript to know if the step is negative or positive, so it just keys the condition based on the relative positioning of start and end rather than on the sign of the constant step.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense but it seemed to me that 1/2 could be recognized as constant expression.

Comment: To permit expressions it would have to check that it is composed purely of integers - too much complexity.

Comment: You have to realize that CoffeeScript is a source translator, not a compiler. It doesn't have nor want to have the machinery to detect that 1/2 is a constant expression (since to do that, it'd need a javascript interpreter).

Comment: For example, `"asdf".charCodeAt(2) / 50` is also a constant expression. `Math.sin(32)` is a constant expression.

Comment: Thank you guys for additional comments. @Chuck pointed out that standard way is 'with additional condition' and there is special optimization for constants. That's main issue and reason why I accepted his answer. I don't want to argue what should be recognized as constant or not. Just merely expressed what could be expected at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

This is constant vs. expression, rather than integer vs. fraction.  When the step is a constant (such as `2`), CoffeeScript knows whether `step` is positive at compile time and outputs the correct code for that.  When the step is an expression (such as `1/2`), it needs to determine whether it is positive at runtime.

Unfortunately, CoffeeScript appears to recognize fractional number as expressions regardless of how they are written (`0.5` or `1/2`), so there's no simple way to avoid this problem.